# Applying Grease Pencil ink strokes where I mean for them to be in 3D space

Tags: grease-pencil

I have a 2-part grease pencil question: Why can't I get the ink to draw where I want it to draw in 3D space, and how do I snap my current ink strokes in my grease pencil object's canvas?

The video capture I did https://youtu.be/JXET1Sjjwno shows the problem I'm having and it also shows how the canvas has become offset from the ink and how it's at a weird angle from the ink. I know about setting the tool to Origin, Surface, Cursor, or Stroke and View, Side, Top, Front, or Cursor.

I'm sure my problem here partly has to do with understanding these things better. But I'm still kind of lost. Basically, the video capture shows a sketch of a guy in a standing pose.

All I want is to be able to draw the next keyframes of his pose in the same 3d space as his standing pose, and I'm guessing that at least *part* of the key is to have the grease pencil canvas realigned so that the standing pose's drawing is flat (or, er, "flush") against the canvas's surface - and that once I do that, it's a matter of knowing what to select from those Origin, Surface, Cursor, or Stroke and View, Side, Top, Front, or Cursor options. Is there anyone who can advise?

Apologies for any follow up questions, I'm in that phase where my mind just hasn't totally grasping the whole thing even though some things have bee starting to click.